# Setting an incremental ID in the TD tag in a table when using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, tags, html-table

I am new to Angular JS so this might be a really stupid question. Anyway, I am trying to get a table filled with data using the ng-repeat directive. I can populate the table with data perfectly. However, what I am struggling with is getting the id in the td tag to increment with every row that it outputs. So, in good old HTML the source would be:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
     <td id="1">John</td>
     <td id="2">Ian</td>
     <td id="3">Nick</td>
     <td id="4">Raymond</td>
    <tr>
    </table>
```

How do I set the table ID to increment by 1 when populating the table using Angular JS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's most likely you wouldn't even need that ID in angular app. What do you want to use it for?

Comment: @charlietfl, what I want to do is have the opportunity to copy each field to the clipboard. For that I need a unique td id as I am using [link] https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: still wouldn't need ID, you would set that up in angular  directive and directives expose the element itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $index.

```
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
  <td id="{{$index + 1}}">{{ x.Name }}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

look at this fiddle: [ng-repeat with index](https://jsfiddle.net/lotyu/wa563oou/)

Comment: spot on! that is just what I was looking for!